# strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2 error when building CNN-LSTM model

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I receiving this error: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,1), activation='relu',input_shape=(10,7,1),strides=1)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1),strides=2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,1), activation='relu',strides=1)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1),strides=2)))
    #model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(TimeDistributed())
    model.add(LSTM(64, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

what should I do to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

If you use `padding='same'` the error may disappear that's because this will add padding whenever needed. In general for an input image with size of `i`, kernel size of `k`, padding of `p`, and stride of `s`, the output image from convolution has size `o`: [image] and the fraction part must be integer for the error not to appear. The equation represents one dimension at a time if image size (8,5) and kernel size (2,1) then the output width is `(8-2*p-2)/s + 1` and so on.

Comment: The error comes from the conv2D part. the input is a matrix either way that have rows and columns. let the rows be the width and the columns be the height and apply the equation.

Comment: `same padding` will let the output have the same dimensions as the input. you need to make sure that the set of the hyper parameters won't result a fraction output dimension.